# Text() does not display write value of variable in runtime

Tags: android, flutter

I have a step in a stepper

```
 Step(
                    title: Text("XXXX"),
                    content: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13),
                        color: Texte.color_blue,
                      ),
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Text(
                              'XXXX\n' +
                                  Texte.gesamtkaufpreis +  <- Static string variable in file Texte.dart
                                  "€",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                  fontSize: 18),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      height: 100,
                    ),
                    state: StepState.complete,
                    isActive: true),
```

I'm using a `PageView` with `PageController`.

These variables like `Texte.gesamtkaufpreis` will be changed in diffrent pages.

On my `Huawei P30 Lite Android 10` everything works fine.

On Samsung A51 Android 10 is the default value of `Texte.gesamtkaufpreis` displayed in the `Step` of the `Stepper!` -> So its like the value `Texte.gesamtkaufpreis` does not get changed!

No I tried to play a bit with `setState(){}` and `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_)` to force a "repaint" later and in some degree it works...

But my question: Whats this a weird behavior...

Answer (score 0):

Use recommended string concatenation for dart

```dart
Text(
  'XXXX\n '
      '${Texte.gesamtkaufpreis}'
      '€',
  style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      fontSize: 18),
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
);
```